How to test Controller with sign in user on Rails 8 authentication
I just try the new Rails 8 with build in authentication, and have this issue when testing Controller using minitest.
Here is the error after running rails test. Since Rails 8 build in authentication is quite new, after further research I still not sure which steps that I miss.
Failure:
TicketsControllerTest#test_should_get_index [test/controllers/tickets_controller_test.rb:12]:
Expected response to be a <2XX: success>, but was a <302: Found> redirect to <http://www.example.com/session/new>
Response body: 

Here is the simplified code for test/controllers/tickets_controller_test.rb
require "test_helper"

class TicketsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @category = categories(:one)
    @user = users(:one)
    sign_in @user
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get tickets_url
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get new_ticket_url
    assert_response :success
  end

  private

  def sign_in(user)
    post new_session_url, params: { email_address: user.email_address, password: "password" }
  end
end


Fixtures test/fixtures/users.yml
<% password_digest = BCrypt::Password.create("password") %>

one:
  email_address: one@example.com
  password_digest: <%= password_digest %>

two:
  email_address: two@example.com
  password_digest: <%= password_digest %>


Dev environment is using .devcontainer with Postgres 16

Don't manually set password digests in your fixtures (or anywhere else for that matter). Set the cleartext password. The digest is an implementation detail that only the model should know about.

Oops silly me. After further debugging looks like I made a beginner mistake.
On Rails 8 new build in authentication, here is the authentication routes that you can find via rails routes | grep session
| Named Route   | HTTP Verb | Path                         |
|---------------|-----------|------------------------------|
| new_session   | GET       | /session/new(.:format)       |
| edit_session  | GET       | /session/edit(.:format)      |
| session       | GET       | /session(.:format)           |
| session       | PATCH     | /session(.:format)           |
| session       | PUT       | /session(.:format)           |
| session       | DELETE    | /session(.:format)           |
| session       | POST      | /session(.:format)           |


So the mistake is I was using the wrong route new_session_url but the correct answer is session_url. Here is the updated method of sign_in
def sign_in(user)
    post session_url, params: { email_address: user.email_address, password: "password" }
  end

And to made this reuseable, we can move this method into test_helper.rb
